# How to change the width of h:outputLabel

Tags: css, jsf, facelets

I am having a hard time trying to change the width of my h:outputLabel, but I still could not get it changed.

By using CSS, I can change the color, font, frame, anything but NOT the WIDTH.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTML [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) element which is generated by `h:outputLabel` is by default displayed as a widthless `inline` element. You need to set its CSS [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) property to `block` to be able to change the width.

E.g.

```
label {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
```